# Search in customized List View with Textwatcher

Tags: android, listview, search, textwatcher

I'm taking too much time on customized search.

I want make a searching with textwatcher. But, I confused how to implement it in my code. Can anyone tell me , How I will implement it in my code or how I will use addTextChangedListener(){} in this code.

```
editTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

 @Override
 public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

 }

 @Override
 public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
         int after) {

 }

 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
 }
});
```

For completition I'm showing the class that have been created:

**Daftar_Masakan.java** (FoodList)

```
public class Daftar_Masakan3 extends Activity{

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> DaftarMasakanAndro = new 
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

private static String link_dft_masakan =
        "http://10.0.3.2/masakan/masakan_andro/daftar_masakan_andro.php";

public static final String TAG_ID = "id_masakan";
public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama_";
public static final String TAG_GAMBAR = "gambar";

JSONArray masakan = null;

ListView list;
LazyAdapter adapter;
EditText inputSearch;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.pencarian);

    inputSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    DaftarMasakanAndro = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    new AmbilDataJSON().execute();

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = DaftarMasakanAndro.get(position);

            //memulai intent baru
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail_Masakan.class);

            in.putExtra(TAG_ID, map.get(TAG_ID));
            in.putExtra(TAG_GAMBAR, map.get(TAG_GAMBAR));
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }); 
}

public void SetListViewAdapater(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>daftar_masakan) {
    adapter = new LazyAdapter(this, daftar_masakan);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class AmbilDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Daftar_Masakan3.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Mohon Tunggu Men...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            JSONObject json= jParser.AmbilJsonUrl(link_dft_masakan, "GET", params);
            //untuk mengecek data di background proses
            //Log.d("hasil json", "Hasil json :"+json.toString()); 
            try {
                    masakan = json.getJSONArray("daftar_masakan");

                    for (int i = 0; i < masakan.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ar = masakan.getJSONObject(i);

                        String id_msk = ar.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String nama_msk = ar.getString(TAG_NAMA);
                        String link_gbr = ar.getString(TAG_GAMBAR);

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        map.put(TAG_ID, id_msk);
                        map.put(TAG_NAMA, nama_msk);
                        map.put(TAG_GAMBAR, link_gbr);

                        DaftarMasakanAndro.add(map);
                    }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        SetListViewAdapater(DaftarMasakanAndro);

                    }
                });
            }   
        }

}
```

This for Lazy Adapter in my code :

**LazyAdapter.java**

```
public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
public ImageLoader imageLoader;

 public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;
    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
}

public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    if (convertView == null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tampil_baris_daftar, null);

    TextView id_masakan = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.kode);
    TextView nm_masakan = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.nama_); 
    ImageView thumb_image = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.gambarthumb); 

    HashMap<String, String> daftar_masakan_andro = new HashMap<String, String>();
    daftar_masakan_andro = data.get(position);

    id_masakan.setText(daftar_masakan_andro.get(Daftar_Masakan3.TAG_ID));
    nm_masakan.setText(daftar_masakan_andro.get(Daftar_Masakan3.TAG_NAMA));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(daftar_masakan_andro.get(Daftar_Masakan3.TAG_GAMBAR),thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

What change should be there in my code , that my search will be execute . Plz I am beginner in Android. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't understand your question. What method to use for what?

Comment: Refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_auto_complete.htm

Answer (score 0):

Modify LazyAdapter so that it implements the Filterable interface and override getFilter() method.

Now Create a class by extending Filter class and provide the implementation of the two overrided methods.

[This](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html) code example will illustrate you how to achieve it programmatically.